# How to authenticate to Cloud Function using a node.js client

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-node, google-auth-library-nodejs

I have a node.js application running in GKE that needs to be able to make a server-to-server call to a Cloud Function that has permission configured to only allow the service account configured on the GKE pod to invoke it. So basically, the node.js has an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to the credential key json file mounted on a volume.

Also for local development, it would be nice if it just uses my user account credentials stored with gcloud sdk configuration.

I've figured out how to authentication using a service account credential. Here is the code, assuming the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable contains the path to the credential key json file:

```
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library'

    const url = 'https://REGION-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/RECEIVING_FUNCTION'
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
        clientOptions: {
            additionalClaims: {
                target_audience: url
            }
        }
    })
    const client = await auth.getClient()

    const res = await client.request({ url })
    console.log(res.data)
```

A slight variation is this way:

```
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library'
    const client = new JWT({
        keyFile: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
        additionalClaims: {
            target_audience: url
        }
    })
```

But I'm still not sure how to do this with user account credentials in local development. The closest solution is using `cURL`:

```
        curl -i https://REGION-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/RECEIVING_FUNCTION \
        -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

So there is a way, but how do I do it in javascript?

Comment: Why not use the service account locally too? Then, rather than trying to ride your `gcloud` credentials, you can use the same flow locally as you're using on GKE.

Comment: I am doing that now. I’m trying to determine if user account creds is also an option.

Comment: Got it. I did a brief search, found Google's oauth2l but I think you'll have to reimplement the web-based flow to take your user account and generate the JWT for the identity token.

Comment: Or `child_process`  make the `gcloud` call and process the result

Comment: Hmmm: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#choosing-the-correct-credential-type-automatically

Comment: @jacob did find a solution?
I am also trying to call a CF from one of our node js applications we have in our GKE cluster, I am still not sure how I can get the identity token of our service account.

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik The solution is the second code block in my question above.